# what is the meaning of ${PWD:A}?

Tags: zsh

I am reading some zsh scripts and found this syntax `${PWD:A}`. I know what $PWD is and the `bash` variable substitution syntax (largely thanks to [this excellent tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html)). Despite of that, I haven't found any docs that explain about the ${variable:flag} syntax for `zsh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${PWD:A}` returns the symlink-free absolute path of `$PWD`. It does so by:

- prepending the current directory
- resolving any `..` and `.`
- resolving symbolic links, if the system has the `realpath` system call - which modern systems do.

As `$PWD` already *is* the absolute path of the current directory and does not contain `..` or `.` elements (at least it really should not), `${PWD:A}` only has to resolve any symbolic links.

---

The `${name:flag}` syntax allows the use of *History Expansion Modifiers* on parameters.

It actually *is* explained in the section [*Parameter Expansion* of the *ZSH Manual*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) (see also `man zshexpn`). Unfortunately it is just a single sentence in the text and not listed with the other `${nameXXXXX}` expansions:

> In addition to the following operations, the colon modifiers described in Modifiers in History Expansion can be applied: for example, `${i:s/foo/bar/}` performs string substitution on the expansion of parameter `$i`.

A list of the available modifiers can be found in the subsection [*Modifiers* under *History Expansion*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers). In the case of `A`:

> `a`
>
> Turn a file name into an absolute path: prepends the current directory, if necessary, and resolves any use of `..` and `.` in the path. Note that the transformation takes place even if the file or any intervening directories do not exist.
>
> `A`
>
> As `a`, but also resolve use of symbolic links where possible. Note that resolution of `..` occurs before resolution of symbolic links. This call is equivalent to a unless your system has the `realpath` system call (modern systems do).

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks